# Highstock tickPixelInterval is not working

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have an issue with tickPixelInterval of highstock.
    When we click on the Zoom buttons, accordingly the data should be shown.
    If we click on Day(1d) button, it should exactly show the one day data and date format on x-Axis should start with 00:00 and end date with 23:59, the time interval must be one hour.
If we click on the 1M,3M,6M buttons, it should display the data accordingly, and the date format/Interval on X-Axis  interval must be one day.
Is it Possible with Highstock? Here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe83S/1/)
    How can we increase length of the x-axis?

```
    $(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {

            inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 280,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 5,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, 
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            },
            {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 0//default show the last 5day's graph

            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            xAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         ordinal: false,
         tickInterval: 24*60 * 60 * 1000,//For One Day
         minTickInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000,//For One Hour
         tickPixelInterval: 300,
         startOnTick:true,

    },
              scrollbar: {
            //height: 10,
            enable: true
        },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : data,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                shadow : true,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
               pointInterval: 24*60*60*1000 
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I totally updated my answer. I used ***tickPositioner*** to ensure that my xAxis is like I want. In my example (jsfiddle at the end), when you click on the buttons OR you move the navigator at the bottom, the xAxis is repositioned, with the following behavior:

- If range is 1 day max => 1 tick every hour
- If range is between 1 day and 1 month => 1 tick every day
- If range is between 1 month and 1 year => 1 tick every month
- If more than 1 year displayed, 1 tick every year

You can fully customize theses values.

To avoid overlapping, I also added ***labels*** property on xAxis

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector : {
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 280,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'day',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1d'
                }, {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m'
                }, 
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m'
                },
                {
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 6,
                    text: '6m'
                }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                selected: 0//default show the last day's graph
            },
            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                ordinal: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                minRange: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // One day max zoom
                labels : { y : 20, rotation: -45, align: 'right' },

                tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
                    var xDataRange = max - min,
                        positions = [],
                        tick = min;

                    positions.info = {higherRanks: {}};

                    if (xDataRange <= 86400000) {
                        // If range is 1 day max => 1 tick every hour
                        increment = 3600000;
                        positions.info.unitName = "hour";
                    } else if (xDataRange > 86400000 && xDataRange <= 2592000000) {
                        // If range is between 1 day and 1 month => 1 tick every day
                        increment = 86400000;
                        positions.info.unitName = "day";
                    } else if (xDataRange > 2592000000 && xDataRange <= 31536000000) {
                        // If range is between 1 month and 1 year => 1 tick every month
                        increment = 2592000000;
                        positions.info.unitName = "month";
                    } else {
                        // If more than 1 year displayed, 1 tick every year
                        increment = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                        positions.info.unitName = "year";
                    }

                    // Create ticks
                    for(tick = min; tick - increment < max; tick += increment) {
                        positions.push(tick);
                    }
                    positions.info.totalRange = positions[positions.length - 1] - positions[0];
                    return positions;
                }
            },
            scrollbar: {
                enable: true
            },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : data,
                marker : {
                    enabled : true,
                    radius : 3
                },
                shadow : true,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                pointInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // Serie point interval set to 1 day
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fe83S/9/

Comment: Hi Nicolas, In the current example I don't have  hourly data, but actually i have hourly data, i added minRange still have same issue. the time interval on x-Axis is showing  only one day[9.May], i want here x-axis time interval should be 1 hour[9:00,10:00,11:00,...]

Comment: If you want hours on the xAxis, change the xAxis "tickInterval": set it to `60 * 60 * 1000` instead of `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`.

See update: http://jsfiddle.net/fe83S/4/

Comment: Nicolas,Thank you very much for your efforts. I have zoom buttons like 1d,1m,3m,6m,1y and All. If we click on the 1d[day] button, then x-axis time/tick interval should be 1 hour[9:00,10:00,11:00,...], other wise(if we click on 1m,3m,6m,1y,All) time/tick interval should be one day[8May,9May,....]. And X-Axis labels Must not be overlapped.

Comment: @Prasad: I fully updated my answer with your last requirements: xAxis is changed with hours when 1d display, and overlapping handled with labels rotate

Answer (score 0):

You can use or `tickInterval` or `tickPixelInterval`, not both of them.

Now, in general such functionality isn't supported by Highstock, however you can manage tick positions using [`tickPositioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner). Just return proper ticks(timestamps), then in [`xAxis.labels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter) format labels to render proper date formats.

Comment: Hi Pawel, I am very new to HighStock and jquery. i tried with tickPositioner, but its not working, i don't know were was i made mistake. here in  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fe83S/3/)

Comment: If we click on the Zoom buttons, x-axis tick interval should not be changed, except for day button. and the x-axis lables should not be overlapped each other.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? For it works fine. Just a side note: you have set 1d = 5days..

Comment: Its not  working. I set 1d = 5days,becoz if I set 1d = 1days, 1d button is disabled. Please  check for 3m,6m,All zoom buttons and see x-axis labels. Thanks

Comment: It's caused by your data granularity - it's 1day, so Highstock disables 1D button. You can either set `allButtonsEnabled` or `minRange`. See second case: http://jsfiddle.net/fe83S/6/ Btw, change unitName to 'hour' instead of 'day'.